# How can I reference a dictionary with boolean terms as values in a while-loop statement?

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

I have this dictionary:

```
flips_left = {'front flip': True,
              'side flip': True,
              'back flip': True
}
```

All the values are True

And I have this while loop:

```
while flips_left[flip_choice] == True:
            flip_choice = raw_input("Do a flip ")
            if flip_choice in flips_left:
                if flips_left[flip_choice]:
                    print flip_lines[flip_choice]
                    flips_left[flip_choice] = False
                else:
                    print "You already did a %s" % flip_choice
            else:
                print "That is not a type of flip"

        print "Great! You completed the WOD!"
```

I basically want a way for the while loop to exit when all the values in the dict are false.

Comment: Sorry for the condition statement in the while-loop I have here was just for testing out the other features of the loop. I'm aware that this will make the loop repeat infinitely.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`any()` tests each of the elements of the passed iterable for their trueness.

```
while any(flips_left.itervalues()):
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to structure your code that avoids scanning `flips_left.itervalues()` repeatedly

```
for flip in flips_left:
    while True:
        flip_choice = raw_input("Do a flip ")
        if flip_choice in flips_left:
            if flips_left[flip_choice]:
                print flip_lines[flip_choice]
                flips_left[flip_choice] = False
                break
            else:
                print "You already did a %s" % flip_choice
        else:
            print "That is not a type of flip"

print "Great! You completed the WOD!"
```